# Get Dynatree marked items from $_POST in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, dynatree

I'm using **dynatree** plugin but when I do:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

in the page where I receive the data I can't see Dynatree selected options? Why? How I can get this data in order to process it in my PHP script?

Comment: is it a post request or a get request?

Comment: @Ibu is a POST request since other form elements are printed right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266485/post-treeview-data) and change a bit of code I made it to works. This is the result:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
        var tree = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree");
        var selKeys = $.map(tree.getSelectedNodes(), function(node) {
            return node.data.key;
        })

        $("#selcs").val(selKeys);
});
```

Hope can help others